# How to resolve "Spark-Submit Error: Failed to load class" issue?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I am new to Spark / Scala, I tried to execute some sample scala program and facing some issue on this. Please find the steps I tried so far,

I have created the scala class (object) **Sivam** under the package **com.dhana.MyScalaDemo**

Step 1: Started Master 
Step 2: Started Slave with above Master URL (Able to see both the Master & Worker node in localhost:8080 UI) 
Step 3: Submitted to Spark as **spark-submit --class com.dhana.MyScalaDemo.Sivam --master spark://10.xxx.xx.xxx:7077 file:///C:/Users/DHANABALAN/workspace/MyScalaDemo/target/MyScalaDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**

Getting the error as below, 
**Error: Failed to load class com.dhana.MyScalaDemo.Sivam.**

Could you please assist me with this?

Comment: can you update your question with pom.xml or build.sbt and the contents of Scala file?